# Laravel dependency injection when setting controllers to a route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I'm looking for a good solution to allow users of my package to change controllers that are bound to routes. Currently I have found this solution:

```
Route::get('/settings', app(OverviewController::class)::class)->name('settings.overview');
```

But this seems kind of inefficient as the method doesn't accept an object, only the class name. Is there a better way of using dependency injection for this purpose?

Another solution would be using config files but I want to avoid that as I want other packages to be able to inject whatever as well.

If it's not possible to use dependency injection for this purpose, what are better solutions short of creating my own system?

Comment: What inefficiency? Do you mean you are resolving a class out of container using ```app(OverviewController::class)```, then passing the class name to the route, so Laravel will resolve the class again?

Comment: @AliRahimi Yes, exactly. Apart from the fact that it's not very pretty, if you have some heavy dependencies I can imagine that resolving the class twice isn't very efficient. Though caching would take care of that I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel will use it's dependency management when resolving that class (see `Illuminate\Routing\Route::getController`). You can just do this:

```php
Route::get('/settings', OverviewController::class)
```

Comment: ...How did I not even consider this? Thank you very much!